# individual rounded corners (NOT all corners)

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I'm trying to get rounded corners on the TOP corners of a bitmap only. Using RoundedBitmapDrawable i can get rounded corners on all corners but how can i get it on only the top ones?

Code i'm using to get all corners rounded:

```
Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.login_background, options);
RoundedBitmapDrawable dr = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), src);
dr.setCornerRadius(convertToPixels(context, CORNER_RADIUS));
myView.setBackground(dr);
```

Comment: RoundedBitmapDrawable does not allow you to specify what corners to round, it does them all

Comment: Yeah.... That's kind of my problem in a nutshell. I found BaseCanvas.drawRoundRect() but was unable to dig further in to see how it actually draws the corners :/

Comment: I am not aware of where you want to use your bitmap after, but this library can be of help, it has possibility to round specific corners only - https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations.

Comment: You could use xml drawables for this. You can specify individual corners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make this using [Glide transformations](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations).

[RoundedCornersTransformation](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations/blob/master/transformations/src/main/java/jp/wasabeef/glide/transformations/RoundedCornersTransformation.java) actually can round all corners with the same radius (not solving your issue).
But i probably would recommend you to use [MaskTransformation](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations/blob/master/transformations/src/main/java/jp/wasabeef/glide/transformations/MaskTransformation.java).
Draw 9-patch drawable with required rounded corners and pass it to the transformation.

Also you can try writing your own custom Glide transformation (copying or extending [RoundedCornersTransformation](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations/blob/master/transformations/src/main/java/jp/wasabeef/glide/transformations/RoundedCornersTransformation.java)): https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Transformations

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot use a 9-patch :/ Thanks for the library suggestion

Answer (score 1):

If your are using Glide 3.7 =>

```
    val multiLeftTopCorner: MultiTransformation<Bitmap> = MultiTransformation(
        RoundedCornersTransformation(context, 15f, 0, RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.TOP_RIGHT),
        RoundedCornersTransformation(context, 15f, 0, RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.TOP_LEFT)
    )

    Glide.with(context)
        .load(IMAGE_URL)
        .asBitmap()
        .transform(multiLeftTopCorner)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.no_image)
        .into(imageView)
```

If your using latest Glide version 4.13

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .transform(new GranularRoundedCorners(75, 75, 0, 0))
            .into(imageView);
```

**But the better option is ShapeableImageView(Material library com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView)**

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_image" />

imageView.setShapeAppearanceModel(imageView.getShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 10)
        .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 10)
        .build())
```

You can also apply in the xml the shapeAppearanceOverlay parameter:

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
      app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/customRroundedImageView"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_image" />
```

with:

```
 <style name="customRoundedImageView" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">0dp</item>   
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">8dp</item>
  </style>
```